# AuthService always injected at the default state

Tags: angular

here is my code

```
import {User} from '../models/user';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {AuthHttp} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Config} from '../app.constants';
import {Observable, ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public currentUser: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
  public loggedIn = false;
  constructor(public http: Http,
              public authHttp: AuthHttp,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  public setCurrentUser(user: User) {
    this.loggedIn = true;
    this.currentUser.next(user);
  }

}
```

this the routing

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    children: [
      {
        component: HomeComponent,
        path: ''
      },
      {
        canActivate: [CanActivateGuard],
        component: UploadComponent,
        path: 'upload',
      },
      {
        component: RegisterComponent,
        path: 'register'
      },
      {
        component: LoginComponent,
        path: 'login'
      },
    ],
    component: WebComponent,
    path: '',
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class WebRoutingModule {
}
```

when the use login this code set this.loggedIn to true

```
let user = new User(data.user);
this._auth.setCurrentUser(user);
```

the problem happen after loggin in

here my debug result

on [web.component.ts](https://github.com/MoustafaElkady/You360-Web-Client/blob/master/src/app/web/web.component.ts)  i added on toggleSearchInput method `console.log(this._auth)`

```
  toggleSearchInput() {
    console.log(this._auth)
    this.searchInputExpanded = !this.searchInputExpanded;
  }
```

when i click the button it console log to me the correct _auth with loggedd in = true

on [guard.service.ts](https://github.com/MoustafaElkady/You360-Web-Client/blob/master/src/app/services/guard.service.ts) i added on canActivate method `console.log(this._auth)`

```
  public canActivate() {
    console.log(this._auth)
    if ( !this.logged ) {
       this.router.navigate( [ 'login' ] );
    }
    return this.logged;
  }
```

and check the console every time i click upload .. it console to me auth service just like nothing happen to it, the loggedIn = false even after logging in ... do you have any idea why is that happing ?

why the service not changing

Comment: do you have multiple modules where you use your service?

Comment: here is the full code https://github.com/MoustafaElkady/You360-Web-Client/tree/master/src/app the problem in src/app/services/guard.service.ts
when i use it in src/app/web/web-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service is instantiated for each module which imports it. If you want to use your service across multiple modules, you need to put in in one module (SharedModule  for example) and import, import it once with .forRoot(), and in your other modules import it the normal way. Like this:

**SharedModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ..., HttpModule ],
  declarations: [
     ...
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        ...
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ..., SharedModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [ ... ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**WebModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ..., SharedModule ],
  declarations: [...]
})
export class WebModule { }
```

Comment: auth service depend on http, where have i add the HttpModule in shared module

Comment: thats worked, but I'm confusing should i add all imports in shared ? like     CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,

Comment: Just what you need for your things inside of SharedModule. So that you can use SharedModule in another module which does not need FormsModule, without the overhead

Comment: is there any article explan that topic in details?